# grouped stacked bar plot of different datasets stored as np.arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a balancing problem and I want to compare some data. I want to do that, by creating stacked barplots for different years. For each year, I want two stacked barplots of different datasets. I am trying to create kind of a "grouped stacked bar plot". I managed to create the 2 stacked bar plots I want to compare, but they are still in two different plots. I am now trying to merge the two plots into one. Here is an example:

```
    data    = np.array([[20, 40, 30, 20], [20, 40, 30, 20], [20, 40, 30, 20]])
    data2   = np.array([[90, 10], [90, 10], [90, 10]])
    x = ['2020', '2025', '2030']

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1=plt.subplot()
    for i in range(data.shape[1]):
        bottom=np.sum(data[:,0:i], axis=1)  
        erzeugung = ax1.bar(x,data[:,i], bottom=bottom, width=0.3, label="label {}".format(i))
    ax1.bar_label(erzeugung, padding=3)

    
    ax2=plt.subplot()
    for i in range(data2.shape[1]):
        bottom=np.sum(data2[:,0:i], axis=1)  
        verbrauch = ax2.bar(x,data2[:,i], bottom=bottom, width=0.3, label="label {}".format(i))
    ax2.bar_label(verbrauch, padding=3)
    
    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show(fig)
```

I feel like this should create two subplots in my figure, but somehow it doesnt. I think Im really close, but stuck. What am I missing here?

Thanks for that solution, it worked. I am now having another Issue. Im adding a legend, by using

```
plt.legend(label_data, bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1))
```

label_data behing my labels for the bars, with a length of 14. Problem is, the colors repeat after 11 labels. How can I get matplotlib to use more colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the positions for the x ticks labels as numbers `0, 1, 2`.  And then subtract a bit for bar positions to the left of the label position, and add a bit for bar positions to the right. Note that due to numpy's broadcasting and vectorization, `x_pos - 0.2` subtracts `0.2` from each individual element of the `x_pos` array.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[20, 40, 30, 20], [20, 40, 30, 20], [20, 40, 30, 20]])
data2 = np.array([[90, 10], [90, 10], [90, 10]])
x = ['2020', '2025', '2030']
x_pos = np.arange(len(x))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(data.shape[1]):
    bottom = np.sum(data[:, 0:i], axis=1)
    erzeugung = ax.bar(x_pos - 0.2, data[:, i], bottom=bottom, width=0.3, label=f"label {i}")
ax.bar_label(erzeugung, padding=3)

for i in range(data2.shape[1]):
    bottom = np.sum(data2[:, 0:i], axis=1)
    verbrauch = ax.bar(x_pos + 0.2, data2[:, i], bottom=bottom, width=0.3, label=f"label {i}")
ax.bar_label(verbrauch, padding=3)
ax.set_xticks(x_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(x)
ax.margins(y=0.1) # some extra padding to place the bar labels
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: grouped stacked bar plots]

Comment: How can I set the labels and colors for each piece of the stack?